# How to remove class from multiple elements in reverse order?

Tags: jquery

I have a toggle-like interaction that adds a class to a list of items, then removes the class from all items upon second click. I am doing `if else` to achieve this, but am failing trying to get the class removal to occur in the reverse order.

I've been working with `.reverse().each` and `get().reverse().each` but can't seem to include it properly. Can that be done with the `if else` or does it need to be done differently?

To clarify, the class is added to each item `.row` with a delay starting with the first item. I want it to start with the last item when the class is removed.

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  var interval = 0;
  $.each($('.row'), function() {
    // Check if .row is active 
    if ($('.row').hasClass('active')) {
      // Remove class at interval
      var item = $(this);
      setTimeout(function() {
        item.removeClass('active')
      }, interval);
      interval += 80;
      // If not...
    } else {
      // Add class at interval
      var item = $(this);
      setTimeout(function() {
        item.addClass('active')
      }, interval);
      interval += 80;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.row {
  background: #ccc;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}

.active {
  background: green;
  width: 200px;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}

button {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<button>Click to run</button>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iraishere/dvtjqoge/2/)

Comment: When you say you want the effect to run in the reverse order, do you mean that the green bars should animate out from the bottom row to the top?

Comment: Move the `if` *outside* the `.each()` to increase.. clarity. Then one can observe the ordering of each and ordering of relative intervals are 'forward'. So if either (*cough* the order of the `each` *cough*) was reversed, it would be backward or - last to first. Moving the `if` outside the loop should make this easier to see.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan — Yes, sorry, I added that clarification in the body above. Thank you.

Comment: Upon moving the `if` outside the loop, consider a selector such as `.row.active` (and `.row:not(.active)` as the inverse to limit and show unification of the initial selection (regardless of order).

Comment: @Ira thanks for the clarification, I added an answer for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that by 'running the effect in reverse' you mean that you want the green bars to animate out from bottom to top, then you can use `reverse()` to reorder the collection before you run the loop.

In addition you can simplify the logic slightly by using `toggleClass()` instead of having the `if` determine state. Try this:

```js
let $rows = $('.row');

$('button').click(function() {
  var interval = 0;
  let $btn = $(this).toggleClass('foo');

  let $orderedRows = $btn.hasClass('foo') ? $rows : $($rows.get().reverse());
  $orderedRows.each(function() {
    var item = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
      item.toggleClass('active')
    }, interval);
    interval += 80;
  });
});
```

```css
.row {
  background: #ccc;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}

.active {
  background: green;
  width: 200px;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}

button {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<button>Click to run</button>
```

Comment: This is much simpler and easier to maintain. Thank you.

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each( $('.row').sort((a,b)=>{
    if (a.offSetTop>b.offSetTop) return 1; 
    return -1;
}), function(){....
```

Sort the elements by offSetTop descending before sending to the function

[Fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/omks0j6e/)